# ffmpeg records 5 frames per second on a device that cheese records at 20 fps

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture

Running the following `ffmpeg` capture on my built in webcam:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video0 output.mkv
```

I get only 5 fps and see this message:

```
The driver changed the time per frame from 1/30 to 1/5
```

When I record using cheese I get what looks like 20 fps on that device. And `v4l2` seems to claim it can do 30 fps.

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
    Name        : Motion-JPEG
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 800x600
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x360
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 160x120
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)

    Index       : 1
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
    Name        : YUYV 4:2:2
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 800x600
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x360
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 160x120
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
```

When I run ffmpeg:

```
Output #0, mjpeg, to 'output.mjpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 5 fps, 5 tbn, 5 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 mjpeg
```

My guess is that it's recording in raw form from the device and doing the encoding in ffmpeg. If this is correct, how would I get ffmpeg to use the mjpeg native format?

Comment: try the "threads" switch with value 3 or 4 if on a PC

Comment: @RobertRowntree That number depends on the amount of cores your CPU has, you shouldn't recommend some arbitrary number without explanation like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to record in the native compressed motion jpeg format supported by my webcam. Once I got that configured (see below) it records at 30 fps at full resolution.

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -c:v mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy output.mov
```

Note the `-c:v` (video codec) before the `-i` (input) indicates what recording codec the device should be using (mjpeg is supported natively on my webcam), and the `-c:v` (video codec) after the `-i` (input) indicates what recording codec ffmpeg should convert to. `copy` does not change the codec, it simply copies the bytes that were provided by the device.

Comment: You are transcoding the input. Add `-c copy` just before `output.mov` to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks, I did discover that the hard way. I updated the answer. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: `copy uses the same codec as was provided by the input.` --> no. `copy`, as it says, copies the stream packets over. If you had put `-c:v mjpeg` in its place as well, that would also be the same codec but transcoding would have taken place.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the verbiage, that's what I meant, but english is tricker than even a bash script. :) Updated.

Comment: This does not work on some Logitec Webcams because they employ a proprietary MJPEG format.

Comment: MJEPG won't be appropriate for all webcams, you'll need to check what formats are natively supported by your specific webcam and use the appropriate format.